# Is it possible to fire a checkbox command from a ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, checkbox

I have a checkbox databound to a bool property in my view model called "ViewType". If "ViewType" is true then the checkbox is checked, otherwise it's not.

The thing is, the checkbox needs to be checked on and off from the view model rather than mouse click to fire off the command.

The said checkbox:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="ViewTypeCheckbox" IsChecked="{Binding ViewType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Command="NavigationCommands.GoToPage" CommandParameter="/views/membership.xaml"/>
```

Unfortunately the command only fires by mouse click. I'm not entirely sure how to make this work using style triggers or data triggers. My most recent try being:

```
    <CheckBox x:Name="ViewTypeCHeckbox">
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ViewTypeCHeckbox, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Button.Click">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="NavigationCommands.GoToPage" CommandParameter="Views/membership.xaml" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </DataTrigger>
    </CheckBox>
```

But this doesn't work either...
Is there any alteration I could make that could trigger the command?

Comment: Can you post the ViewModel Code

Comment: Don't understand your question, you can set the property `ViewType` to `true` or `false`, it will be reflected on your view.

Comment: You can just bind the IsChecked property to the ViewModel's bool property. and at the ViewModel's bool property's property changed event, you can navigate to next page (GoToPage command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using a `RoutedCommand` you're already outside of the pure ViewModel realm so there's no reason not to just hook up event handlers for `Checked/Unchecked` (which will fire when the Binding changes) and execute the command from there.